# Webpack resolve alias works with sass but not when importing javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I get this error when importing a React component with an alias:

```
ERROR in ./src/components/EventsFeed/EventsFeedItem/ItemFooter/ItemFooter.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module '~components/LikeButton' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/react-feed/src/components/EventsFeed/EventsFeedItem/ItemFooter
 @ ./src/components/EventsFeed/EventsFeedItem/ItemFooter/ItemFooter.js 15:18-51
```

My goal is to resolve the directories automatically so that I don't have to deal with something like this in every import: "../../../../...". I'm importing the component LikeButton like this:

```
import LikeButton from '~components/LikeButton';
```

It works when I import SASS inside style.scss files like this:

```
@import '~/stylesheets/utilities/settings';
```

Here's how my webpack.config.js file looks:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

const sassLoader = 'css!sass!postcss?indentedSyntax=scss&includePaths[]=' + path.resolve(__dirname, './src');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    entry: [

        './src'
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',  // this exports the final .js file
        publicPath: '/public'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015,plugins[]=lodash'] 
            },

           {
                test: /\.scss$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', sassLoader) 
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
        new ExtractTextPlugin("./bundle.css")
    ],
    postcss: [
      autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 2 versions']
        })
    ],

    resolve: {
        modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src'],
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.scss'],
        root: [path.join(__dirname, './src')],

        alias: {
            stylesheets: path.join(__dirname, './src/stylesheets'),
            components: path.join(__dirname, './src/components')
        }
    }
};
```

This is how my src folder looks like:
[image]

Comment: `modulesDirectories` would be more helpful, `~` does not have any special meaning for `import` in JS

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you zerkms!

Comment: The `~` means "node_modules" folder.